# How can I extract path parameters from url?

Tags: javascript, rest, url

Let's say I have an object that contains the values:

```
 const pathParams = { schoolId :'12', classroomId: 'j3'}

and I have a path: school/:schoolId/classroom/:classroomId
```

I would like to extract: 'schoolId' and 'classroomId' from the path so that I can later replace them with their corresponding values from the pathParams object. Rather than iterating from the pathParam object keys, I want to do the other way around, check what keys the path needs and then check their values in the object.

I currently have this:

```
function addPathParams(path, paramsMap) {
  const pathParamsRegex = /(:[a-zA-Z]+)/g;
  const params = path.match(pathParamsRegex); // eg. school/:schoolId/classroom/:classroomId -> [':schoolId', ':classroomId']
  console.log('--params--', params)
  let url = path;
  params.forEach((param) => {
    const paramKey = param.substring(1); // remove ':'
    url = addPathParam(url, param, paramsMap[paramKey]);
  });
  return url;
}


function addPathParam(path, param, value) {
  return path.replace(`${param}`, value);
}
```

Does this look robust enough to you? Is there any other case I should be considering?

Here's a couple of tests I did:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you want the code to ultimately look like? In other words, do you want something like `getParams('school/:schoolId/classroom/:classroomId')` and it returns `{ schoolId: null, classroomId: null }`? Or do you want to do something like `setParams('school/:schoolId/classroom/:classroomId', pathParams)` and it returns `school/12/classroom/j3`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to eventually set the values as you have it `school/12/classroom/j3`, but first, I want to check what params the path requires, because I want to cover the case where the pathParams object doesn't contain a param the path requires.

Comment: Once I have the params the path requires, then I can easily iterate though the params, get their values and call `path.replace(`:${paramAttribute)`, pathParams[paramAttribute]`)

Comment: The problem with your current solution is with params that are named similarly, like `:school` and `:schoolId`. If `:school` came first, that would get replaced with the value, and you'd end up with a path like `/schoolId/12Id/school/:school/` (it would replace the first instance only). Just changing it to ```replace(`/${param}/`, `/${pathParams[param]}/`)``` would fix that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for pointing that out,  I can't follow your example. For instance, I tried this: `const path1 = 'org/:schoolId/:school/classroom/:classroomId'
const paramsMap = {schoolId:'123', classroomId:'abd', school:'3hs7'}`, and that resulted in `org/123/3hs7/classroom/abd`

Comment: the replace will work on the order the parameter shows in the path, so I think, although I may be wrong, that it should still work as is, right?

Comment: If it works, it works. Ship it :).

Comment: Thank you for the approval sir :)